Formatting strings in Dask/DuckDB
I have some parquet data which looks like :
Name,Count,Result
ABC,500,"123,456,789,..."
ABC,499,"321,456,789..."

with Count numbers being present in the Result string. I would like to replace the Result of any row with Count=499 with 32767, 500 times. I'm hoping this could serve as an error of sorts. I thought about replacing with np.nan, but not sure how this would work with the string. In dask I was hoping this would be easy with :
fill_values_499 = np.array2string(np.full((500,), 32767), separator=",").strip("[]")
df[df["Count"] != 500]["Result"] = fill_values_499

But on examining the data afterwards I found this missed rows. I couldn't find a way to use the data as an array first and then do the filling based on the Count column.
So overall :

Can this operation be done in Dask? Maybe there's a more efficient way to approach the problem.
Could this operation be done in SQL, something like DuckDB/SQLite? For my data this might be faster since I'm just on one machine.

EDIT: e.g another approach is exploding the strings to have one number per row, but I think this transformation is very memory intensive (at least in Dask) and so isn't practical.

it's a strange way to create 'invalid' rows. If you don't care of Result of row with Count = 499 why don't you just replace it with empty string?

@RomanPekar yes, it can seem strange. I just need to have a way of telling where the errors are. At a later stage I will turn many Result rows into a 1d array of integers, and at that stage I will do something with the 32767s. You're right that I don't care about the values themselves though.

you can use case when Count = 500 then repeat('32767,', 500)[:-2] else Result end as Result in DuckDB

For efficiency, be sure to avoid creating the long string from scratch more than once. If using DuckDB, one way to do this would be using a MATERIALIZED CTE like so:
WITH replacement(r) AS MATERIALIZED 
  (select rtrim(repeat('32767,',500),','))
  UPDATE t
  SET Result = (select r from replacement)
  WHERE Count = 499;


As an aside, it might be worth considering whether the Result string shouldn't be split ("unnested") into separate columns.

Yes, unnesting may be worth it. What about in the case that there is also a time column in the data? I would have to make a time for each value/etc.

Sounds like you have some database engineering issues.  What about a second table?

I have duckdb.duckdb.BinderException: Binder Error: Can only update base table! when replacing t with "data", which is from data = duckdb.read_parquet(...). Is there an easy workaround?

The second table might work yes, but I wouldn't know (at least in SQL) how to give each element in Result an increasing time. It would make the data much easier to handle I'm sure

Figured this out, but need to iron out some more implementation details on my end. Thanks for your help!

Regarding the "Binder Error": you could: CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t AS SELECT * FROM 't.parquet'; WITH replacement(r) .... UPDATE t ....; COPY t TO 't.parquet';

You could use Ibis to generate SQL. Here I used DuckDB, but Ibis can work with a Dask backend. There's probably a little overhead in doing the "32767," * 500 part in Python, but probably not huge.
import ibis
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ibis.options.interactive = True

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["ABC", 500, "123,456,789,..."], 
     ["ABC", 499, "321,456,789..."]],
    columns=["Name", "Count", "Result"]
)

con = ibis.duckdb.connect()

t = con.read_in_memory(df)

to_replace = t.Count == 499
count_modified = to_replace.ifelse("32767," * 500, t.Result)
t = t.mutate(Result=count_modified)

t

[OUTPUT OMITTED]
# First 200 characters of generated SQL
str(t.compile())[:200]

'SELECT "t0"."Name", "t0"."Count", CASE WHEN "t0"."Count" = CAST(499 AS SMALLINT) THEN \'32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767,32767'




Thanks for the answer, never heard of Ibis but seems cool :)

You can use DuckDB for that:
duckdb.sql("""
    select
        Name,
        Count,
        case when Count = 500 then repeat('32767,', 500)[:-2] else Result end as Result
    from <??>
""")

Or polars:
df = pl.scan_parquet(...)

df.with_columns(
    pl
    .when(pl.col.Count == 500)
    .then(pl.lit("32767").repeat_by(500).list.join(","))
    .otherwise(pl.col.Result)
)

